# threejs bump map scale/tiling

Tags: three.js, scaling, texture-mapping, tiling, bump-mapping

I'm trying to apply a bump map to a mesh imported at runtime, using Three.js.

I can actually apply the bumpMap, but I need to specify the vertical and horizontal scaling for the map (somebody call it tiling). I saw that for bumpMapping there is only one value for the scale, and not a Vector2 as I thought.

I saw that there is bumpMap.repeat property, but I think it's not what I need.

Can anybody give me some advice, please?

Thank you very much

I just noticed that I can't post snapshot, 'cause I'm new here. If anybody is interested, please let me know how to send the images.

Comment: does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304906/in-three-js-how-to-repeat-the-texture-map-like-gl-repeat
The bumpmap is a regular texture map and should own all the properties every Three.Textures own.

Comment: I don't think it is something useful..my problem is not the repetition of the texture..what is going on is that my bumpMap has a scale of (8,8) and standard bumpMap scale is 1..so, my map is bigger that the default settings..i don't need repetition, i just need to tell three.js that my map has to be scaled in order to fit correctly, instead of being stretched